# QML + PyQt5 Material Style

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qt-quick

I have my simple PyQt5 application, which includes QML file. I want set Material style for app, but it returns error.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1    

ApplicationWindow{
  title: qsTr('Qml app')
  id: mainWindow
  width:  500
  height: 400
  color: '#f6f6f6'
}
```

How can I fix it? Help me,please
My python code is:

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == '__main__':
     myApp = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     engine = PyQt5.QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
     ctx = engine.rootContext()
     ctx.setContextProperty('main',engine)
     engine.load('styles/mat.qml')
     win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

     win.show()
     sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\My\Python programms\app8.py", line 12, in <module><br>
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]<br>
IndexError: list index out of range<br>
```

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: what is the error message??

Comment: And what is your python code?

Comment: Edit your post and add your code

Comment: @eyllanesc, yeah, I had a problem with adding my code to comment, so I changed the main question and placed my code in it

Comment: Are you sure the path of the file mat.qml is in a styles folder?

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, of course

Comment: You could try placing mat.qml in the same folder as the app8.py file and changing engine.load ('styles / mat.qml') to engine.load ('mat.qml')

Comment: @eyllanesc, oh. Now I runned programm with console and there I found: QtQuick.Controls.Material is not installed:( isn't it default with QtQuick?. The path was right

Comment: What version of PyQt do you have?

Comment: @eyllanesc PyQt5 version 5.3.1

Comment: Material Style is enabled from version 5.7 on Qt

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank you:) updating my Qt now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material Style is available from version 5.7 on Qt.